# As of 2019, what are the most important questions in zero-knowledge research?

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs

Important meaning; where the most research is being focussed. Maybe because a break-though seems possible or a break-through would have big consequences.

Any questions that are being researched vigorously?

Comment: If you'd asked a few week back, I'd have said NIZKs from worst-case assumptions. But this was recently solved by Peikert and Sheihan: https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/158.

Comment: @Occams_Trimmer Would a new open question be efficient NIZKs from worse case assumptions?